# Deploying Windows forms application with local database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have few doubts to clear from you all. I had enough to google now. I am very pure to `C#`.

I have followed some `tutorials` and then I did `Windows Form App with using local database`.

It has used `Visual Studio 2010` local database file is `.sdf` format. Then I deploy the project as describe in the tutorial. And I run my application on my PC.

It has no severs installed. But application is working file. I can insert, update and delete data using my app.

After all those. I have developed same application in `Visual Studio 2013` using `.mdf` local database file. Deployed. But it's not working now.

I wanted to know.

1. what is the best practice to work with databases?
2. How can I deploy my project with database?
3. Can I run windows form app in any pc that haven't sql severs?
4. (sdf) is not more available in VS13. So, What is the local database similar to (sdf) now?

Please, I hope you all have kind reply.

Comment: "it's not working" is very generic. What doesn't work, and what more information about the problem do you have?

Comment: @YoryeNathan `Not Working` means, When I deploy the application in VS13. Insert, Update and Delete part not working. I wanted to know. what is the `local database` in VS13?

Comment: @yeshansachithak http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx

Comment: @yeshansachithak: again, just saying "it's not working" fails to convey anything useful, even if you put other words in front of it. Are the queries returning errors? Are you getting errors connecting to the database? What are the errors?

Comment: @siride this is the [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/368e1d/connecting-to-local-database-in-C-Sharp/) that I followed. I used VS2010. But when I used VS13 to do. There have no option to create (sdf) database. So, I built it using (mdf). So, That's the reason it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the second application is not working because it needs an instance of SQL Server up and running. SQL Compact edition (sdf) doesn't require a server to run, while SQL Server database (mdf) does.

About your other questions.

There is not a "best practice", you use one or another depending of your requirements.

You can use an SQL script to create your database during installation process.

Yes, you can run winforms in any machine with a .net runtime installed, it doesn't have to do at all with SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, I know. I've researched. Problem is, before deploy the application I have add some data to my database. Then I deployed. I can see my data grid view that database data is their. When I insert the data it's working. But when I close the app and opened again. That newly inserted data was not in the data grid view. :-/

Comment: @yeshansachithak That will require asking another question, and show us some code.

Comment: this is the [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/368e1d/connecting-to-local-database-in-C-Sharp/) that I followed. I used VS2010. But when I used VS13 to do. There have no option to create (sdf) database. So, I built it using (mdf). So, That's the reason it's not working